# JavaFX Combobox row with ImageView+Label

Tags: combobox, imageview, javafx-8

I have a combobox which is fill whith a list of Ejercicio class objects (Ejercicio contains id, name..).

```
ComboBox lstPrueba=new ComboBox<Ejercicio>();
//I get a list of Ejercicio from DAO an add all to the combobox
lstPrueba.getItems().addAll(new EjercicioDAO().obtenListaEjercicios("something"));
```

I need that all combobox row´s have a ImageView (png Image names is base on Ejercicio id, because png name equals to Ejercicio id) plus a label (with Ejercicio´s name).

I try but not work:

```
    class FormatoCelda extends ListCell<Ejercicio> {

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Ejercicio item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/img/"+String.valueOf(item.getId() + ".png")));
        ImageView imgv = new ImageView(img);
        if (item != null) {
            setGraphic(imgv);
            setText(item.getNombre());

        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And in initializate method:

```
    lstPrueba = new ComboBox<>();
    lstPrueba.getItems().addAll(new EjercicioDAO().obtenListaEjercicios("something"));

    lstPrueba.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Ejercicio>, ListCell<Ejercicio>>() {
        @Override
        public ListCell<Ejercicio> call(ListView<Ejercicio> list) {
            return new FormatoCelda();
        }
    }
    );
```

I´m a newbie in JavaFX. I search over Internet and StackOverFlow but I can´t find a good example on filling a control list type like combobox with a image+label.

Sorry, my English isn’t very good.

Comment: How is it not working? You can't see images with labels?

Comment: Yes, if only show label with some text take from Ejercicio (like the name) it works. But when I try to show a label with image nothing appears.

Comment: Check if the classloader really can find the image you specified. Check is there any exceptions.